# Generic function for the fusion of the array of the objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am coding some program that among many other operations have one that from the two unordered arrays makes one ordered and lists all the elements of these two arrays into that one specific, and so far I have been doing great, however I got stuck on trivial problem and the thing is I can't find what the hell is wrong with this code( maybe, it's because I'm so sleepy/tired/etc... Any help is appreciated.

```
template < typename T>
void meltTwoRustyArraysAndProduceShinyOne(const T* a, int na, const T* b, int nb, T*& c, int& nca
{
  c = new T[nc=na+nb];
  int ia = 0, ib =0, ic = 0; 
while (ia<in || ib < nb )
 c[ic++] = ia==na ? b[ib++] : b==nb ? a[ia++] : a[ia]<b[ib] ? a[ia++] : b[ib++];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the problem with it? What output does it produce and what should it produce? That many ternary operators in a row is just asking for debugging hell.

Comment: It is, but that's the way we programm here, hursh and no mercy to debuging.:P Anyway I have got the solution to this problem, it seems to me that it just was, as I expected, a very trivial problem, caused by tiredness. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part with "b==nb ? b[ia++]" is incorrect. Change it to "b==nb ? a[ia++]"